A list created from Excel Export creates a allitemsg.aspx view and also goes to Edit mode
I think is easier to create and build columns using Excel formulas in Excel.
So, I Export from a Excel table to create a new sharepoint list, but it gets a default view called allitemsg.aspx?
I much prefer the format of the list since it keeps the columns very narrow.

I manually have to delete the leftmost column, which is icon called Type.
The main problem is I don't want to go directly into Edit mode. The list contains hyperlinks that aren't easy to click in Edit mode.

Can I somehow restore the view to the standard view behaviour?
Maybe restore alliteimsg.aspx to allitems.aspx, but keep the nice narrow formatting ?
RESOLVED: see comment below

Here is an older stack exchange article describing the same problem. https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/156994/set-task-list-to-standard-view-not-quick-edit-mode A solution seems to be to not use the datasheet view, is it correct?

RESOLVED: It seems like a DataSheet view becomes the default view when you export a list from Excel. (and the view is named allitemsg.aspx, don't know what the "g" stands for)
The solution is to create a new Standard view and set is as the default view. (I kept the allitemsg view and renamed it "datasheet view" since that view is more convenient when editing the list)
